# Slice an array to multiple parts

Tags: javascript, arrays

My example:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];

let slice = (source, index) => source.slice(index, index + 4);

let length = arr.length;

let index = 0;

let result = [];

while (index < length) {
  let temp = slice(arr, index);
  
  result.push(temp);
  
  index += 4;
}

console.log(result);
```

Logging:

> [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18]]

I want to slice the array to multiple parts for per 4 items `[1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]...`

The code is working fine.

I have 2 questions:

1/. Is there another way to do that via using inline code? Ex: `result = arr.slice(...)`

2/. After I define:

```
let push = result.push;
```

why cannot I still use:

```
push(temp)
```

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined

**UPDATE:** I've updated the solution based on the answers. Hope it's helpful.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];

let result = [];

arr.forEach((x,y,z) => !(y % 4) ? result.push(z.slice(y, y + 4)) : '');

console.log(result);
```

Logging:

> [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18]]

Comment: `let push = result.push;` extracts the function so that it's no longer associated with any certain object. You would need to use `push.call(result, temp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do it

```
var chunckArray = function(array, chunkCount){
     var chunks = [];
     while(array.length){
         chunks.push(array.splice(0, chunkCount);
     }
     return chunks;
}
```

A non consumative way :

```
var chunckArray = function(array, chunkCount){
     var chunks = [],  i, j;
     for (i = 0, j = array.length; i<j; i+= chunkCount) {
         chunks.push(array.slice(i, i + chunkCount); 
     }
     return chunks;
}
```

Comment: It would be worth shallow cloning it to keep the desired behaviour and not mutate the original

Comment: You are right buddy

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it using a for loop which will give you a same result:

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];

console.log(arr.length);
var result=[];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=4) {
  result=arr.slice(i, i+4);
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using a simple reduce (see [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0D57sDE9YaZN3et7x5no?p=preview)):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];

var counter = -1;
var result = arr.reduce((final, curr, i) => {
  if (i % 4 === 0) {
    final.push([curr])
    counter++;
  } else {
    final[counter].push(curr);
  }

  return final;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

You can tweak the `4` and substitute it with a variable `chuckSize` this will allow you to be able reapply to other things - you could also wrap this in a function with paramerters `(array, chunkSize)` if you wanted to